# how to run redis monitor command in redis lua script instead of redis-cli monitor

Tags: redis, lua

I want to use redis lua to implement monitor command instead of redis-cli monitor. But I don't know how.

`redis.call('monitor')` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can not call `MONITOR` from a Redis Lua script - `MONITOR` is a blocking command so it would block your script forever if allowed to be invoked.